# MySQL query checking for nothing being returned

Tags: mysql, ruby

My code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'mysql'

@mycon = Mysql.new 'localhost', 'user', '', 'test'

time_check = @mycon.query("SELECT v_status FROM test.movement WHERE test.movement.id = '1001'")
time_check.each_hash do |test_result|
  test_report = test_result['v_status']

  if test_report.empty?
    @test_says = "UNKNOWN"
  else
    @test_says = test_report
  end
end

puts @test_says
```

Querying for '1001' returns nothing as it's not in the database, but for some reason the `if test_report.empty?` is not working. I tried `nil?` as well but that didn't work. Where no record exists in the database I need to update `@test_says` to be "UNKNOWN".

If I query something that does exist in the database then I get the expected result.

In IRB, looking for something not in the database I get back:

```
=> #<Mysql::Result:0x00000000f482b0>
```

otherwise I get the expected result when it is in the database.

Can anyone help me get the expected result of UNKNOWN where there is no hit against the database?

**Update**
With help from @K M Rakibul Islam I switched to using the mysql2 gem and the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'mysql2'

@mycon = @mycon = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => "localhost", :username => "user", :database => "test")

time_check = @mycon.query("SELECT v_status FROM test.movement WHERE test.movement.id = '1001'")
  if time_check.count == 0
  @test_says = "UNKNOWN"
  else
time_check.each do |test_result|
  test_report = test_result['v_status']
    @test_says = test_report
  end
end

puts @test_says
```

Returns `UNKNOWN` as desired. I had to move the `.count` part as shown above because my var `test_report` was only a string and not the mysql2::result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the [mysql2](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2) gem, you can use the [`count`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/mysql2/0.3.13/Mysql2/Result#count-instance_method) method:

```
if test_report.count == 0
  @test_says = "UNKNOWN"
else
  @test_says = test_report
end
```

You have to make sure you call `count` on a `Mysql2::Result` object.

Comment: using the mysql2 gem - If I do that I get ``count': wrong number of arguments (0 for 1+) (ArgumentError)` any idea? the docs are not much help to me :( http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/mysql2/0.3.13/Mysql2/Result#count-instance_method

Comment: Can you try using mysql2(https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2) gem instead of mysql gem? Then it should work.

Comment: that was with the mysql2 gem. mysql2 (0.4.1). Just had a play. if i query something that does exist then I get that argument error. If I query something that does not exist then I still get nothing returned rather than 'UNKNOWN'

Comment: `count` method is implemented on `Mysql2::Result` object and used like that. Are you sure your `test_report` is a `Mysql2::Result` object? can you do: `puts test_report.class` and see what's the class?

Comment: `puts test_report.class` returns `String`

Comment: ah, that's the problem. You have call the `.count` method on a `Mysql2::Result` object. You can actually do that before starting the loop. `time_check` should be a `Mysql2::Result` object and you can do the check before you start the loop.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91937/discussion-between-user3788685-and-k-m-rakibul-islam).

Answer (score 0):

Using the mysql2 gem, you can use `each` instead of `each_hash`.

This should work, and the block should never be called when there is no result:

```
time_check.each do |test_result|
  test_report = test_result['v_status']
  ...
end
```

Comment: yep - found that! got it going in the end. just having coffee and i'll update the question with the end result.